# Decouple compile and linking into two steps

Tags: linker, segmentation-fault, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a main file, which calls a function defined in the shared lib.

```
// main.c
int main()
{
    int x[2] = {1, 2};
    int y[2] = {3, 4};
    int z[2];
    addvec(x, y, z, 2);
}
```

The shared library is the following code

```
// addvec.c

void addvec(int *x, int *y, int *z, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
         z[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}
```

I used `gcc -shared -fpic -nostdlib -o libevctor.so addvec.c` to make a shared library.

Then I compiled main.c without linking.

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
```

Finally, I linked these two parts:

```
ld -rpath=$PWD -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -m elf_i386 -e main main.o libvector.so -o prog
```

Everything works fine so far. However, when I run  `prog`, segmentation fault occurs.

Besides, I used `readelf` for `prog` and found the value of addvec in .dynsym is 0:

```
symbol table '.dynsym' consists of 5 entries:
Num:  value:  Size   Type    Bind   Vis   Ndx   Name
0:   00000000   0     NOTYPE LOCAL  DEFAULT UND
1:   00000000   0     FUNC   GLOBAL DEFAULT UND addvec
2:   0804934c   0     FUNC   GLOBAL DEFAULT 10  __bss_start
....
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: `void addvec(int *x, int *y, int *z, 2)` Is this your real code?

Comment: @AlexF Thanks for your reminder. It's `int n`.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should not use `ld` (or `gold` or any other linker) explicitly because invocation line is very target-dependent and fragile. Just link with `gcc`:

```
gcc -Wl,-rpath=$PWD -m32 main.o libvector.so -o prog
```

In your particular case you were probly missing `crt` object files which handle program startup and libc setup (add `-v` to see actual `ld` invocation line).

Comment: Using `-nostdlib` to link a shared library is bogus as well.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yup, forgot to mention.